# Linux based USB HID device , how to?

Tags: usb, yocto, hid, libusb

I would like to configure my Embedded Linux kernel in USB-HID device mode and considering, I am new to USB, So I don't even have much idea about terminology for this particular mode to do grep in kernel code or find the right documentation, any help on this topic will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x194.html

Before cross compiling update .config with USB gadget. Just search for USB in kernel .config